# Select query when one column value is equal with column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have this query where I need to select subtraction value of parent with busines of the codes.

For example let's say in the container table we have Parent value 0.39 and the child value 0.7 than the value fromthe selection would be -0.31‬.

Now this value (-0.31‬) I need to multiply it with the value of Quality column which is found in another table. Than I need the top 3 values. That means ordering by desc ofcourse.

But ofcourse it should be multiplied when NetNames is equal with BetNames and Codes column value is equal with  one the columns in table container. (Q_1, Q_2, Q_3).
I'm lost here guys.

Below is info about my tables.

```
/*Table Container*/
BetNamesID |   Parent_B_Id   |  Year  |   Month   |   Q_1 |   Q_2   |  Q_3 
    1         null              2020       5        0.36    0.3       0.21
    6            2              2020       8        0.39    0.64      1.0
    7            1              2020       9        0.76    0.65      0.29
    8            3              2020       13       0.62    0.34      0.81
    9            2             2020       2        0.28    0.8       1.0

/*Table Configuration*/
NetNames     |  Codes  |   Quality   
 Test 1         Q_1          5     
 Test 2         Q_5          7     
 Test 3         Q_2          24     
 Test 4         Q_3          98    
 Test 5         Q_4          22     

 /*Table BetNames Info*/
     ID     |  Parent_B_Id  |    Name   
      1         null             Test 1    
      6            2             Test 2    
      7            1             Test 3     
      8            3             Test 4    
      9            2            Test 5
```

What I have done until now is this query :

```
SELECT
  child.[BetNamesID],
  child.[Parent_B_Id],
  child.[Q_1] - parent.[Q_1] AS Q_1,
  child.[Q_2] - parent.[Q_2] AS Q_2,
  child.[Q_3] - parent.[Q_3] AS Q_3,
  // this is just a test case.. this is how it is supposed in my mind(child.[Q_3] - parent.[Q_3]) * qualityvalue AS Q_3, //this is how it is supposed to be
  , n.name

  FROM [dbo].[Container] child
    join [dbo].[Container] parent on child.Parent_B_Id = parent.BetNamesID
    join dbo.NetNames n on n.id = parent.Parent_B_Id //with this I get the names for BetNamesID
```

And this is the result of my query until now:

```
BetNamesID |   Parent_B_Id  |   Q_1 |   Q_2   |  Q_3 
    3            2             0.21    -0.3      -0.1
    5            4            -0.39    0.64      -0.9
    8            5             0.99    0.65      0.59
```

What I need now is to multiply the values of Q_1, Q_2, Q_3 columns, with the values found in Config table (Quality column), only when BetNames is equal with NetNames and Codes row value is equal with Q_1 or Q_2 or Q_3 column.

These are the expected values.

```
 BetNamesID |   Parent_B_Id  |   Q_1               |   Q_2                  |      Q_3 
  3            2            1.05‬(0.21 * 5)       -7.2(-0.3* 24)            -9.8 (-0.1* 98) 
  5            4            1.95(0.39*5)         15.36(0.64*24)             -88.2 (-0.9*98)
```

How does the new Table come in play? How can I join? How does the where condition work in this case?

Comment: I don't really follow the logic you describe here. perhaps you could also include the expected results you're after for your sample data?

Comment: Ofcourse @Larnu I will now.

Comment: Where is `dbo.NetNames` table?

Comment: There isn't @Sami . It's the configuration table that one.

Comment: Can You take a look now @Larnu? Thank You

Comment: The query you've given us doesn't even run (it has a `,` followed by a `,` and references the column `qualityvalue` qhich doesn't exist in any of your tables. Even if you change it to `quality` that column isn't in any of the tables in the `FROM`. How can it give you those results?

Comment: In the example you give you say you have a parent value of `0.39`, which must be `Q_1` on the row with an `ID` value of `5`. you then say the child value is `0.7`, however, that number isn't in your sample data at all, and the parent for `ID` number `5` is `4`; which doesn't exist in your data. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: ofcourse it runs, it just that I mislead, beacause qualityvale it is a test case of mine.. remove that line @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu I simplified a bit.. you can take a look.

Comment: That doesn't explain the description that doesn't match your sample data, @Pavel .

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.